# Hide FileCategoryName if it has no child

Tags: sql-server

I have two table union together

```
                     Files
ID | FileName | FileContent | FolderCategoryId |

                     FolderCategory
ID | FolderCategoryName | FolderParentCategoryId |
```

And Here's my query:

```
WITH UnionFiles(FileCategoryId, FileCategoryName, FileParentCategoryID, FileParentName, FileCategoryType) AS (              
            SELECT fc.ID AS FileCategoryId
            ,fc.FolderCategoryName as FileCategoryName
            ,fcparent.ID AS FileParentCategoryID
            ,fcparent.FolderCategoryName AS FileParentName
            ,FileCategoryType = 0
            FROM [dbo].FolderCategory AS fc 
            LEFT JOIN [dbo].FolderCategory 
            AS fcparent 
            ON fc.FolderParentCategoryId = fcparent.ID

            UNION

            SELECT 
            f.ID as FileCategoryId 
            ,f.FileName as FileCategoryName
            ,f.FolderCategoryId as FileParentCategoryId
            ,ffcparent.FolderCategoryName AS FileParentName
            ,FileCategoryType = 1
            FROM [dbo].Files as f
            LEFT JOIN [dbo].FolderCategory as ffcparent
            ON f.FolderCategoryId = ffcparent.ID
)
SELECT *
FROM UnionFiles
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to hide the `FileCategoryName` that has no child. Is this possible?

Comment: The first half of your union query seems to imply that a folder can only have a maximum depth of 2 (parent and child).  Is that correct?

Comment: yes sir dats correct

Comment: It'll help if you could paste the ddl to create the tables here so people can start helping immediately